# Mapping computed CSS styles to specified ones?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Is there a way to map the [computed style](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-ViewCSS) of a dom element (as retrieved by [`window.getComputedStyle`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle)) to a corresponding `CSSStyleRule` in `document.styleSheets`?

My ultimate goal is to retrieve [*specified values*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specified-value) for dom elements (rather than [computed values](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#computed-value) or [actual values](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#actual-value)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, only IE (with element.currentStyle) allows JS to retrieve the specified values, which is a good thing in my opinion. All the other browsers return the computed values.

I once needed the specified value and the only thing that crossed my mind was to make a CSS parser that would map an element to a rule based on the element's xpath. It would have been some kind of a reversed jQuery, where you would supply a DOM element and it would have returned the CSS rules associated with it after parsing all the loaded CSS. Unfortunately I didn't have the time to start the project.