# $('#elem').css('width') in percentage in jquery 1.5.2 vs 1.7.1

Tags: jquery, css

I'm in the process of upgrading a web application from jQuery 1.5.2 to 1.7.1. In jQuery 1.5.2, it was possible to get the percentage CSS value of an element using $('#elem').css('width'), if the element was inside another hidden element.

**To be clear, I need the CSS value in PERCENTS and I don't know beforehand whether it will be in percents, or px, or em, or whatever.**

For a simple test case, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/strikernl/y3P3A/

It seemed to work in 1.5.2, then no longer in 1.7.1. I added 1.6 in the test just to see if that still worked, and it didn't, so it broke somewhere between 1.5.2 and 1.6 I guess.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there another way of doing what I'm trying?

**"SOLVED", see my answer**

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387419/retrieving-percentage-css-values-in-firefox

Comment: That getStyle() function seems to do the trick, so if all else fails I guess I can use that. But it doesn't really explain why it worked in jQuery in the past and not now. Thanks in any case!

Comment: No problem ;) btw its weird, you should check jquery's source to see the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I found out it's a bug. See here http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10782. It took quite a while to get noticed though apparently (1.6 through 1.6.4, then 1.7 and 1.7.1).

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for :

```
$('#foo').width();
```

you can also get the :

```
$('#foo').outerWidth()
```

or

```
$('#foo').innerWidth()
```

(depending on your padding, border...)

by the way, in jsfiddle, you can include directly jQuery (and many other librairies...look at the left sidebar)

Comment: No, neither width(),outerWidth() nor innerWidth() do what I need. In fact, those don't even do what I need in jQuery 1.5.2, let alone 1.7.1. Also, if you had looked more closely at my example, you'd have seen that I load THREE versions of jQuery, not just the one. I don't think jsfiddle provides that option. I added a new test case so you can see the output of width(),outerWidth() and innerWidth() as well here: http://jsfiddle.net/strikernl/eenRY/2/

Answer (score 0):

can't u do it like this:

```
$('#elem').width();
```

I've updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y3P3A/1/

Comment: Errr, how does that help? You added the percentages literally (between the quotes). I don't in fact know beforehand it's going to BE a percentage. It's kind of the point of my question, actually.

Comment: Ah ok, I figured you knew it was gonna be a percentage anyway. Nevermind then.