# How do I retrieve CSS property in Firefox and Opera exactly how it's written?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, opera

I'm trying to develop a jQuery plugin that utilizes CSS values and modifies them. The problem, however, is that [Firefox and Opera seem to not like keeping track of the units of the property's value](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=707691). In [Retrieving percentage CSS values (in firefox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387419/retrieving-percentage-css-values-in-firefox), the asker wants to get the percentage of a CSS property. I want to get the CSS property as a percentage with javascript if it's specified as a percentage in its CSS or as pixels if it's specified as pixels. I don't want to rely on any libraries other than jQuery, although it doesn't seem to be able to do what I'm wanting either.

CSS

```
#element{
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#element').css('margin-left'); // returns 29px in Firefox, but 10% in Chrome
getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('element')).getPropertyValue('margin-left'); // returns 29px in Firefox, but 10% in Chrome
```

Comment: It does'nt really do that, you'll have to calulate the percentage by using the pixel value of the element, and the pixel value of the parent element, to get the percentage.

Comment: @Xotic750 Firefox and Opera doesn't use getMatchedCSSRules(element) so I have to use getComputedStyle(element). But that's not the problem. The problem is that the return values for the properties are different in different browsers. Firefox "throws away" the original value specified in CSS and (usually) converts it to pixels.

Comment: Do you want to grab width value from inline CSS or external stylesheet? or both?

Comment: @SalmanA Both. It needs to be retrieved from an unknown source.

Answer (score 1):

This example is using css `width`, but the principle can be applied to any attribute that may be specified in %

CSS

```
.oneThirds {
    width: 25%;
    background-color: red;
}
.half {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}
.twoThirds {
    width: 75%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="oneThirds">One third</div>
<div class="half">Half</div>
<div class="twoThirds">two thirds</div>
```

Javascript

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (element) {
    var parentStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element.parentNode);
    var elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    var widthPercent = (parseFloat(elementStyle.width) / parseFloat(parentStyle.width)) * 100;

    console.log(widthPercent);
});
```

Output

```
25
50
75
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/pGPL6/)

On some browsers you may need to do a little rounding of the floating point.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't what I'm looking for. I'm not trying to convert everything into percentages. What I'm trying to do is get the native CSS rule. e.g. it's specified as 20% in CSS and will give you a return value of 20%. If it's specified as 20px, then it will return 20px.

Comment: Then I guess you need to make that 100% clear in your question.

Comment: No problem, but I fear that you may be out of luck there.