# How to know if an element's width is absolute or relative?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm coding a javascript scriptlet on which I'm resizing a DOM element. But I  need to know if the element was originally sized *absolutely* or *relatively*.

Of corse I can read its `clientWidth` property, but it always returns an absolute integer. How can I know if it was originally specified by a percentage number in a CSS? Is there any CSS property -readable from javascript- containing the original width expression?

Comment: `position_prop = document.getElementById(id).style.postion;`

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387419/retrieving-percentage-css-values-in-firefox). Not sure if duplicate

Comment: maybe window.getComputedStyle(elm[, pseudoelement]), this will return a list of css styles that the browser deems as what you see (computed Styles).

Comment: @sadiqevani Thank you. I've tried `window.getComputedStyle`, but it still returns always absolute values in "width" and "height" fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your width value  is inside the tag you can use `document.getElementById("id").style.width`. But if your css is inside a tag style, that's going to make you use jquery for a quick solution or you are going to have to create your own function to extract this value, like this one: [How to get an HTML element's style values in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you. In the link you have posted, I've seen the exact solution I needed: `Element.currentStyle`. Unfortunately, it only works in IE. I guess I'll have to add extra parameters to my javascript function.