# How to get the css width property of an element

Tags: css, dom

I would like to get, in my JS code, the "original" CSS width property applied to an element, not the runtime (computed) width.
eg.

```
.foo {
  width: 50% /* or 123px, or 5em, ...*/
}
```

in this case, I want to get `"50%"`, and not the px value computed at runtime. If value is given in em, I want to get em as result. 
`window.getComputedStyle(foo, null).getPropertyValue('width')`, returns a pixel value (at least on google chrome).
In fact I need the text value of the CSS rule applied to the element.

Comment: Where do you want to get it? In your browser developer tools, in JavaScript, ...?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript

Comment: @KilianStinson, a agree, it's nearly a duplicate, but in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript he wants to get the rule value of a class, in my case I want to get the CSS value applied to my element regardless the classes. Basically I want to get the value after the CSS engine run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving percentage CSS values (in firefox)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387419/retrieving-percentage-css-values-in-firefox)

Comment: @Pete, percentage value is for the example only, if value is em, a want to get em

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @torazaburo, I need to wrap a random element at runtime without impacting the surrounding layout.

Comment: I can't say for sure without more details, but if you mean wrap in another element, such as a `div`, the wrapping div should by default assume the dimensions of its content.

Comment: You just need to step through the `document.styleSheets` collection. Each sheet represents a `<style>` element and contains elements for each of the contained rules. That's reasonably trivial and can be completed with a little help from the debugger and the object explorer. However, this will only catch (easily) instances where a rule exists for one or more of (0)tagName, (1)id (2)class. You're still going to have trouble with rules that include any form of parent/child hierarchy. The general case will be very hard.

Answer (score 0):

`foo.width in pixels / parentElement.width * 100 = foo.width in %`
so in JS for example:

```
var width = document.getElementById('foo').offsetWidth;
var parentWidth = document.getElementById('parentOfFoo').offsetWidth;

var fooWidthPercentage = width / parentWidth * 100;
console.log(fooWidthPercentage);
```

Comment: The implication of the question is that if the `width` value is `10em` then the OP would want `10em` to be returned, similarly if the value is `24vmin`...it doesn't appear to be a problem of converting the width to a percent value, but instead retrieving the assigned value and units (presumably without knowing in advance what those units might be).

Comment: I wouldn't see how that would cause a problem, wouldn't javascript measure the width in pixels (or convert the 10em/24vmin to pixels) anyway? that's how I understand JS anyway.

Comment: JavaScript can definitely convert from `px` to `rem` (or whatever), but to know that a conversion should be performed requires first finding out what units to convert to, which itself involves retrieving the original property-value from the stylesheet(s), at which point the conversion would be unnecessary.